# Is it possible to force ending of (close wait) connections?

Tags: rhel, tcp, lsof, open-files, port

when we run lsof on port 6060 as the following

```
# lsof -i TCP:6060 | more
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
app_lot 3495 root   12u  IPv6  9238779      1t0  TCP *:krb0934 (LISTEN)
app_lot 3495 root   13u  IPv6  9208460      1t0  TCP linux_server45:krb0934->43.55.3.22:5992 (CLOSE_WAIT)
app_lot 3495 root   21u  IPv6  9402392      1t0  TCP linux_server45:krb0934->34.22.50.28:6005 (CLOSE_WAIT)
app_lot 3495 root   28u  IPv6  9208462      0t0  TCP linux_server45:krb0934->54.33.6.161:23096 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

we see many close wait ,

we not want to kill the pid - 3495

is it possible to force closing the - CLOSE_WAIT ?

without restart the application - app_lot

Comment: Are they causing problems?

Comment: yes , we can access the port 6060 from internet browser , example 28.3.22.2:6060

Comment: I will happy to hear from you  opinion , we have huge close wait , so we think application not close the connection as should be

Comment: sorry - yes I mean can’t access port 6060 ( typo mistake )

Comment: I also restart the httpd on that machine but no help

Comment: so any way to force closing these connection without killing the PID of 3495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to close a socket in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state (or any other state) externally. If a misbehaving program is accumulating `CLOSE_WAIT` connections, the only way to free those connections is to kill it.

This is a bug in the application, the best solution is to get it fixed. (I’m not saying that’s feasible or realistic.) Alternatively, you could connect to it with a debugger and close the connections from the debugger...